# How to use already existing type during xml schema registration?

Tags: xml, oracle

I have different `xml documents` which consists of 3 parts: `HEADER`,`BODY`,`FOOTER`.
 `HEADER` and `FOOTER` have similar structure for every document. 
I'm using "`DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.registerSchema`" with "`GENTYPES => TRUE`" to create custom types for every document. 
 I wonder if it's possible to use previously generated types during schema registration?
 Otherwise I'll have to create types for `HEADER` and `FOOTER` over and over again. If I try to use name of an existing type in my `xml schema`, I get an error during schema registration "`header_type already exists`".

Comment: Why not `gentypes=>false`?

Comment: I need objects to store my xml documents before I write them to database. Without objects xml shredding would be rather messy.